# Cross site scripting in asp.net and how to prevent it

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, xss

I recently used a vulnerability scanner for one of my asp.net webforms based websites which is using framework 4.5.

Website was flagged for several vulnerabilities and most of it is related to cross site scripting XSS. one such example is below

**Example 1:**

**Alert group:** Cross site scripting

**Details**: URI was set to `'onmouseover='8HLr(9179)'bad='` The input is
reflected inside a tag parameter between single quotes.

- GET //?'onmouseover='8HLr(9179)'bad=' HTTP/1.1
- Referer: https://example.com/ Connection: keep-alive
- Accept: */*
- Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Host: example.com
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.21
  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21

**Example 2:**

**Alert group:** Cross site scripting

**Details**: URL encoded POST input ctl00$txtSearch was set to the'onmouseover=8qGf(9096)' 
 The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between single quotes.

- GET /search/the'onmouseover=8qGf(9096)' HTTP/1.1
- Referer: https://example.com/ Connection: keep-alive
- Accept: */*
- Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Host: domain.com
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.21
  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21

**Example 3:**

**Alert group:** Cross site scripting

**Details**: URI was set to 'onmouseover='gPIH(9411)'bad='

The input is reflected inside a tag parameter between single quotes.

- /blog/1234/title-of-the-blog?'onmouseover='gPIH(9411)'bad=' HTTP/1.1
- Referer: https://example.com/ Connection: keep-alive
- Authorization: Basic YW5vbnltb3VzOmFub255bW91cw==
- Accept: */*
- Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Host: domain.com
- User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.21
  (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.21

White testing on localhost i injected XXS to my local url `http://localhost:54923/%3Cscript%3Ealert('hello!');%3C/script%3E`

and it generated error on the page

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the
>   client (<).

Does this mean my page is not vulnerable to XSS and after further investigating about XSS in asp.net webform i found few article which talk about senitising input which is being done.

one example which shows that xss can be done easily by setting following in web.config file

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" />
```

Source/: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/preventing-xss-in-aspnet--cms-21801

Is setting `requestValidationMode` enough to prevent XSS attacks as mentioned above or we need to do more.

Comment: tldr; use *proper encoding* whenever relevant.

Comment: @user2864740, could you explain bit more

Comment: just use `escape `

Comment: @Learning - ["Contextual output encoding/escaping \[is\] the *primary defense mechanism* to stop XSS attacks..."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Preventive_measures) This also implies *not* allowing user-supplied data in contexts/ways it *can't* be safely used. The 'LiteralControl', Response.Write, and Control Properties are places of general concern.

Comment: What if in simply sanitize inpute with following code `string filterInput = search.ToLower();

            if (filterInput.Contains("onmouseover") || filterInput.Contains("script") || filterInput.Contains("</style>") || filterInput.Contains("</script>"))
            {
                search = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(filterInput);
            }`

Comment: tldr; That still won't "sanitize" everything safely. Use safely encoded outputs (and limit user input where such cannot be used safely) and then no "sanitation" is necessary. If the user passes in `<script>alert("fail")</script>` but it's written to HTML as `<div id=mycontrol>&lt;script>alert("fail")&lt;script></div>` (by using safe escaping or a context that guarantees correct escaping), then 'whatever'.

Comment: By using escaping consistently everywhere appropriately, second order attacks are also mitigated. Trivial counter example of how the "sanitization" above fails: `onmouseout=stillnotsecure` or `<script src=youlose>`. Don't attempt to sanitize for security - and especially not without help of a proper library! - do sanitize and check allowed values for *business* reasons.

Comment: Going back above: it is the use of `HtmlEncode` (or better, use controls that accept/write raw text) that is relevant, not the "sanitization". However, HtmlEncode *won't* help if applied to the contents of JavaScript or on-event attributes. This is because it is not encoding for the correct context, that is: this is wrong: `fromUser = "alert('stilloops')"; ..; control.OnClientClick = HtmlEncode(fromUser)`. Look at the resulting HTML to see why.